# Upgrade SVN version after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: svn

yesterday I have upgrade my Ubuntu version from 12.xx to 14.04. Everything is ok, excepted my svn server. Now I got a error message and need to update svn version.
After first searching in internet, I found some easy solution [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html).
Anyway, where is my repository of svn?
When I use the order `which svn` I get the link `/usr/bin/svn`. But what I should do now? When I use `sudo svn upgrade /usr/bin/svn` I got a error message translated in english: `svn: E155019 is not a basis of workprint and is impossible to open »/usr/bin/.svn/entries«` .
I suppose, I'm in the false directory, consequently the question is, how I can define the right path to my svn? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find / -type f -name '.svn'` will list all the path containing this directory which is present in each SVN working copy you have on your system.

Change into the top directory found containing a `.svn` one. There is the top of your working copy where you can run `svn upgrade`.

As you certainly checked out the SVN using your own user account (`svn co <repository location>`, you don't need `sudo`. You don't need to run the `svn` commands with `sudo` or all the files checked out will be owned by root. So all editing would have to be done using `sudo` too.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I done my update, terminal show me the right directory, so I have solve this problem already 2 hours ago, but forgot to tell this on the forum. But thank you very much